# Simulate swipe gesture with mouse and snap focused Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, snapping

Scenario :

Select an opened Window, swipe the Window with mouse to either left or right direction for snapping.
Example : User swipe Notepad to left, the Notepad window will snap at left side.

Using : WPF , C#, VS2013

Problem : 
1) How can I check every frame whether the user has moved his mouse or not?

If that succeed, can it work in situation where the WPF application is not focused?
I'm planning to make it minimize to the notification bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, found the solution anyway. Maybe this will help someone who shares the same problem with me.

For mouse swiping gesture
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/189559/Mouse-swipe-gesture-for-net